# ImportError: /home/dminstalluser/script/lib/prctl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I am trying to run a python script, and seems when it try to import a library called `prctl.so`, some error happens:

```
def update_cmd_title():
    """Remove the secure informations in the command title"""
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/script/lb")
    import prctl
    prctl.setprocname(" ".join(sys.argv))
```

but I can find this file `prctl.so` in directory `/home/dminstalluser/script/lib/`,

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dminstalluser dm_group 10344 Aug  1 03:55 prctl.so
```

I search from google, and can find somebody had the same problem, but after i followed their solutions, they all failed, like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dminstalluser/script/lib
```

or run:

```
ldconfig
```

I don't know what's the problem for this error for my case,

Comment: ok, got it, i will update it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 64-bit system, the error is most likely caused by a mismatch between the Python you are running, and `prctl.so` that you've installed.

For example, trying to load 64-bit `prctl.so` into a 32-bit Python, or vice versa, will produce the error you've observed.

Run `file $(which python) /home/dminstalluser/script/lib/prctl.so`. If one of them says `ELF 64-bit ...`, and the other `ELF 32-bit ...`, then that's *exactly* your problem.

The fix is to install `prctl.so` matching your `python`.

Comment: yes, it is exactly the root cause, the package i got from my colleague is not compatible with my platform, which is arm, not x86,